# Check for multiple cases without if statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I created this function which should check for every case, and if one of the case not corresponding then i should get immediately the result.

```js
const addText = (data, addAlternative) => {
        return (data !== 'N/T' || data === 0 || data) ? data : addAlternative;
};
console.log(addText('N/T', 'alternative'))
```

in my case `addText('N/T', 'alternative')` i get `N/T`, but i expect  to get `alternative` word as a result. How to change my statement to check every situation and if one of the situation occurs i have to get the right answer like in the example that i provided?

Comment: `(data !== 'N/T' || data === 0 || data)` resolves to true since `data` is truthy. So you get `data` as return value

Comment: To be clear, `""`, or `undefined` or `null` should also return the alternative, right? In that case take it from the other side: `(data === 'N/T' || (!data && data !== 0)) ? addAlternative : data;` But I don't see what's wrong with `if` statements. That you have to come here to ask how to do something like that means that it won't be clear to you anymore in three months.

Answer (score 1):

```
const addText = (data, addAlternative) => {
        return (data !== 'N/T' || data === 0) ? data : addAlternative;
};
```

Comment: i also need to test for the rest of truthy values of `data`, so i need and `|| data`

Comment: @Asking You do realise that `'N/T'` is truthy. So testing for truthy value for `data` will make it true when it is `'N/T'`. So your logic is `if (false || false || true)` which resolves to true (the true at the end is because `data` contains the string `'N/T'`)

Comment: @slebetman, i know that a string is truthy, this is why a added multiple condition, but how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving `NT` as output, because you are checking the truthy status of `data` parameter isiide the function by using `data !== 'N/T' || data === 0 || data`.

Update that to `data !== 'N/T' || data === 0`, it will work as expected.

```js
const addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty = (data, addAlternative) => {
  return (data !== 'N/T' || data === 0) ? data : addAlternative;
};
console.log(addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty('N/T', 'alternative'))
```

If you want to output data if the param is not defined, just check `!data` inside the condition, there you dont need to add `data === 0` because `!data` will handle `null`, `undefined`, `empty`, and `zero` checks

```js
const addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty = (data, addAlternative) => {
  return (data !== 'N/T' || !data) ? data : addAlternative;
};
console.log(addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty('N/T', 'alternative'))
```

Comment: Given the function's name I guess they want empty inputs to also return the alternative

Comment: @Nitheesh, i also need to test for the rest of truthy values of `data`, so i need and `|| data`

Comment: They want to special case `0`.

Comment: @Asking That should be `!data`, if you want to display `alternative` when data is not N/T and the data is truthy

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent `if (data)` from being tested if data is `'N/T'` but currently it is being evaluated at the end because of short-circuiting.

Your logic is basically:

```
return (false || false || true) ? ...
          ^        ^        \____ because data contains 'N/T'
          |        |         
          |        '-------- data is not 0
     because data is N/T
```

This obviously resolves to true because the `||` operator only needs one of the expressions to be true.

What you actually want is:

```
return (data !== 'N/T' && (data === 0 || data)) ? ...
                        ^
                        |
                   remember De-Morgan's Theorem
                   (google it if you don't know)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addText = (data, addAlternative) => {
        return ((data && data !== 'N/T') || data === 0) ? data : addAlternative;
};
console.log(addText('N/T', 'alternative'))
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Try below */

```js
const addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty = (data, addAlternative) => {
        return (data !== 'N/T' || data === 0) ? data : addAlternative;
};
addDefaultTextIfIsEmpty('N/T', 'alternative')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `data` in `if` statement and you are passing `'N/T'` which changes the value to `false` and according to the logic the value always be `true`. Try this solution.

```js
const addText = (data, addAlternative) => (data && (data !== 'N/T' || data === null || data === 0)) ? data : addAlternative;
console.log(addText('N/T', 'alternative'))
```